# Running total field gives options for Min, Max, etc. but not Sum

Tags: crystal-reports

I wants to design Crystal Reports as follow

### Name                 //(Group)

---

```
Date                   Amount

12/04/2010             100  

12/05/2010             200

Total….                300
```

But there are problem on insert Running Total  summarize by change of group fields.

I have tried by right clicking on field  Insert + Running Total. But there are no option of

**Sum** in **Type of Summery.** There are  following option :

### Type of Summery

Maximum

Minimum

Count

Distinct count

Nth largest

Nth smallest

**How can I add/minus/multiply  Group Wise ?.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the Datatype of Amount column into an `integer` type and check with database again. In crystal reports the sum will appear only to the `number` fields and as your post says the `Maximum, Minimum, Count, Distinct count, Nth Largest, Nth Smallest` will comes only for `varchars`. check [crystal Syntax](http://flylib.com/books/en/4.229.1.28/1/)

Comment: yes you are right it's my mistake but how to minus,multiply and divide it conditional any idea?.

Comment: then you should use formula fields for this purpose, refer to the crystal syntax of minus, multiply and divide

Comment: The matters is solved with your kind help that I have created the formula field with supports of Running Total Fields as per group wise and the tricks works. thanks....