# Crystal Report: Get Minimum Date

Tags: crystal-reports

I have this concern using Crystal Report which I am not really familiar with. Here's my scenario:

I have an existing report to update, I need to add a column (ETA) which has a datetime value. It may return more than one rows per Item No, I need to get the minimum date only per Item No from the result rows.

[image]

I already tried some solution mentioned here http://scn.sap.com/thread/1952829 but found no luck.

I used a suppression formula for the Details section of the report, but haven't succeeded yet.

IF {TableName.DateField} = Minimum({TableName.DateField}) THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE

Any possible things you can suggest me to try? Thanks in advance for this :)

Comment: what is the result of the supression formula?

Comment: The picture above was the result of the supression formula..

Comment: where did oyu place those fields in design?

Comment: What do you mean? I put the fields inside the Details section

Comment: ok then try this: `supress details` and in `group footer` or `report footer `which ever is available there write `Minimum({TableName.DateField}) `

Comment: Alright, I'll definitely try this and will advise you with the outcome. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69175/discussion-between-vinvinvinvin-and-siva).

Comment: Actually i cant chat as it was blocked you can post here your queries

Answer (score 2):

good to get this value from sqlserver side. you just create a function which return a single data (minimum date).

If you wish in crystal report side, it is something you make loop of hundred for a single row display. You can use running total field for this.

Select the field , select summary type and put into the detail section.

or you can create a formula with group name option like

```
Minimum({TableName.DateField})
```

http://scn.sap.com/thread/1952829

http://businessintelligence.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/businessobjects-crystal-l/unable-to-filter-based-on-the-first-date-in-list-of-dates-4912881

please check 
[Running total field gives options for Min, Max, etc. but not Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316552/running-total-field-gives-options-for-min-max-etc-but-not-sum)

http://flylib.com/books/en/4.229.1.28/1/